# rsyslog: discriminate between boots with new files or break line

Tags: linux, embedded, syslog, rsyslog

I've got a system that uses rsyslog for logging. Some of the messages being logged I want to store on the device (error messages) so that if something has gone wrong I can review them later. All works great, problem is the device does not have a real time clock (RTC) so every time I reboot the thing, the rsyslog timestamps start at 0 again. This obviously leads to problems where I am unable to discern if 2 logs happened right next to each other or if the earlier one happened a week ago and the new one only after rebooting.

```
error_logfile          [real time]

0:06:01 error message  [0:06:01]
0:06:55 error message  [0:06:55]
0:10:22 error message  [192:10:22]
```

Is there any way to get rsyslog to create a new log file for every boot? I figure I could do so with a dynamic name, but again no RTC so I can't use the timestamp as the name. Is there some file numbering system I can use? I do have the boot counts of the device stored in a register so I'd like to use that if possible, but I'm unsure how to create a custom property that retrieves it's value from some application that runs and returns the boot count

```
error_logfile1

0:06:01 error message
0:06:55 error message

error_logfile2

0:10:22 error message

error_logfile...
...
```

```
$boots = ./bootC

error_logfile_boot1045

0:06:01 error message
0:06:55 error message

error_logfile_boot1047

0:10:22 error message

error_logfile_boot...
...
```

Alternatively is there any way to insert a "title" log entry into the log file so that I can discriminate between boots? perhaps some way to run a script ONCE when a message is produced and directed to this file? I suppose running it everytime is fine as well and just appending or prepending to the log template, if that's even possible?

```
error_logfile

---BOOT#1043---
0:06:01 error message
0:06:55 error message
---BOOT#1045---
0:10:22 error message
```

Comment: Assuming the time will be set correctly, possibly by ntp, can you not set rsyslog to depend on ntp or whatever sets the time?

Comment: @Bib unfortunately the device is not networked (and cant be) so it's impossible to always have the time set

Comment: Create a file with a counter. Each boot, increase it, write it back, then run `logger` with the count plus some recognisable text.

Comment: Or if it's being logged to `/var/log/messages`, run logrotate and restart rsyslog.

Comment: @Bib logging the bootcount as a message is something I considered, my only problem with it (and why I wanted it in the filename or templated instead) is because there will be A LOT of boots with no errors and I don't want to burn my write count (nand flash) with boot messages and no errors, ideally it would only appear IF an error is logged